# Encoding for k-level qualitatative variable

Tags: feature-extraction

I have a qualitative variable, e.g. `userId`, which could take around 30,000 different coded values ($k$). I would like to represent this variable as a dummy variable. Coding this into a vector of size $k$ doesn't seem to be a good approach. Is there a more compact method for coding for this variable?

Comment: Sure: _hashing_ comes to mind.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more that how hashing would help me here? Do we make a hash of k-vector?

Comment: What I meant is that [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) allows to _compress_ data of arbitrary size to a smaller data set. However, the side effect of that is the presence of _collisions_. I would research potential options of dealing with collisions, in general and in particular context of your data types, so that you can see, if this approach is _feasible_ (I'm not stating that). Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you literally mean more compact, like, taking fewer bytes right? but instead taking on fewer than 30K distinct values? hashing won't help unless there are lots of collisions then. Although this is a well-known technique for very high-dimensional data I'm not sure it's appropriate here.

Comment: Also are you sure you want to predict based on user ID? you normally predict based on qualities of a person, not their actual identity.

Comment: @SeanOwen You are right, but my problem is little different. There are huge number of operations are done on the users. I have to predict the future performance of these actions per user basis.

Comment: I think I got your point. These performance totally depend on userIds but in real I could replace these ids with some properties which contribute to the performance impact and make the model agnostic to the user. But the problem here is that sometimes we have limited domain knowledge, so we club all this feature under a group and give them id(say user id).

Answer (score 1):

There is always clustering techniques you could do that would help you determine how to group userId into a dummy variable.

Comment: So we will still use k-vector but this time k is the number of groups and hence less than number of unique users?

Comment: This is a little redundant though.. the information you add from this clustering is just the info contained in the other features, which are already inputs.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using tree based methods, you can replace the qualitative variables with random numbers or with the counts of each class.

Comment: Even with random they will be qualitative. Numbers would be just labels...!

Comment: Obviously they are unordered random numbers and are still categorical data; however, decision trees don't have a linearity presumption. This means that the splits will sort out the different effects of each category. Imagine only one category is different from the rest. A decision tree will take only two splits to identify this category. If there are 30,000 categories, very likely many of them will have similar effects. A decision tree takes advantage of this when partitioning the data.